# Why is my MySQL query giving a strange answer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So, I'm trying to achieve a dynamic htaccess ban system, and this line of code is causing me huge problems:

```
$ip = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_contactform WHERE Nimi='Christian'");
```

When I echo it out, it gives me the following:

`Resource id #3`

The table contains Christian 3 times, with id's 11, 13 and 10. What's causing this?

Comment: The root cause of this issue is your failure to read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: This is normal behaviour. You should use this resource as an argument of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry, I've only readed the tutorials at w3schools. I'll go and give them something to think about.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen: Welcome to Stack Overflow! w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just don't like the Php.net, it's so messy looking and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ip = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_contactform WHERE Nimi='Christian'");
```

`$ip` will simply retrieve the resource representing the resultset - it is not the data itself.

You will need to look into using:

```
$ip_array = mysql_fetch_array($ip);
$ID = $ip_array['ID'];
```

to get the `ID`.

Also keep in mind that this API `(mysql_*)` is deprecated, so it may be in your best interests to look into alternative MySQL libraries in PHP:

**MySQLi**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**MySQL PDO**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

clearly written in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ip))
{
 echo $result[] = $row;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```